# Prevent render until data has been fetched react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to prevent a component from loading up until it has fetched the data from the API, like Instagram. I want just the old component to keep showing until the new component is ready. How would I do this reactjs, please

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import Main from "../main";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import {
  getBooks,
  getMoreBooks,
  addToLibrary,
  search
} from "../../actions/books";
import { showLoading, hideLoading } from "react-redux-loading-bar";
import BottomScrollListener from "react-bottom-scroll-listener";
class Books extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.props.showLoading();
    this.state = { isFetching: false, search: "", shouldScroller: false };
  }


  // componentWillMount() {
  //   this.props.showLoading();
  // }

  async componentDidMount() {
    if (!this.props.books.length > 0) {
      await this.props.getBooks();
    }
    // this.props.hideLoading();
  }
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.book_next_url !== this.props.book_next_url) {
      setTimeout(
        this.setState({
          isFetching: false
        }),
        800
      );
    }
    if (prevProps.books != this.props.books) {
      this.props.hideLoading();
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    // this.setState({ shouldScroller: false });
    // this.props.showLoading();
  }

  render() {
    if (this.props.booksIsLoading) {
      return <Main />;
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <BottomScrollListener
          onBottom={this.handleScroller}
          debounce={600}
          offset={30}
        />
        <Main />
    );
  }
}
```

I have shown the details above of my whole component that I wat to be rendered.

Comment: That's a very good question. However it's not in accordance with the StackOverflow format. Can you please post your code? Did you try anything?

Comment: I tried putting it in the constructor, also tried componentDidMount but what it does is it loads the component and shows the loader until the data has arrived. What I want is to remain in the old component until the data has arrived

Comment: Hi. Welcome to Stackoverflow! Your question is too broad, please take a look on [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Share some code, what component do you want to hold rendering, how you're calling this component?

Comment: What do you mean by "remain in the old component"? It sounds like you know about conditional rendering, please show at least some relevant code so we can see what you're doing.

Comment: You can use the data from the global state to inside your `render` function. Then the component will be rendered only when it's updated

Comment: can u give me some sample code @GalAbra

Comment: I have added code to the question

Comment: Which component is showing the "old component"? Whatever that parent is, it has to wait for the data to be loaded before switching to the new component. If the data is loaded *inside* the new component, you need to move the loading of the data up into its parent.

Comment: On an unrelated note, it is greatly advisable not to have dozens of lines of JSX in a component; split it up into child components instead.

Comment: @Chris G, How would I do this?

Comment: Do what? Move up the loading of the data? Explaining that is beyond the scope of this question (and this website, to be honest). What exactly is the issue?

Comment: Im using redux too. So its in the global state. Im asking how do I check if the new components has gotten the data in the old component, how do I wait for the data to be loaded before switching to the new component?

Comment: So how and when is the parent of `<Books />` showing `<Books />`? That's where you need to start.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198532/discussion-between-nsj-corps-and-chris-g).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking to switch from old component to data component when data is loaded. The code below shows how you can do that with the `Switch` component.

```
import React, { useEffect, useReducer } from 'react';

const Data = props => (
  <div>
    here is the data: {JSON.stringify(props, undefined, 2)}
  </div>
);

const OldComponent = props => (
  <div>
    this is the old component loading is{' '}
    {props.loading ? 'true' : 'false'}
    <button
      onClick={props.loadData}
      disabled={props.loading}
    >
      load data
    </button>
  </div>
);
//general Switch component function that will render
//one or other based on the switchFn returning true or false
const Switch = (one, other, switchFn) => props =>
  switchFn(props) ? one(props) : other(props);

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'load':
      return { ...state, loading: true };
    case 'received':
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        data: action.data,
        showOther: true,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
const initialState = { loading: false };

const DataSwitch = Switch(
  OldComponent,
  Data,
  //show Oldcomponent if props.showOther is false
  props => !props.showOther
);

export default () => {
  //pretend redux
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(
    reducer,
    initialState
  );
  //loadData action
  const loadData = () => dispatch({ type: 'load' });
  //pretend middleware to get data, will be executed if
  // loading changes
  const { loading } = state;
  useEffect(() => {
    if (loading === true) {
      new Promise(resolve =>
        setTimeout(() => resolve([1, 2, 3]), 1000)
      ).then(data => dispatch({ type: 'received', data }));
    }
  }, [loading]);

  return DataSwitch({ ...state, loadData });
};
```

Comment: The thing is mine is a matter of routing. Not button clicking